# IE 11 does not execute bound events in flatty (twitter bootstrap template) after modal is opened

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

As title says I'm working with flatty, a twitter bootstrap template.

I have a select list that initiates a modal like this.

```
<select size="20" id="selected_items" data-toggle="modal" href="#modal-item-list" class="col-md-4" name="selected_items">
  <option value="0">Item 1</option>
  <option value="1">Item 2</option>
  .... etc .....
</select>
```

Clicking within the list opens up the modal as intended but on IE 11 the modal remains stubbornly empty.

I have an event bound to the options of the list like this :

```
$(function(){
    $('select[name="selected_items"] option').on('click',selected_items);
});
```

The function selected_items contains a $.post to retrieve a json object and dynamically populate the contents of the modal based on what was clicked.

I've tested on Safari, chrome, firefox and opera and it works flawlessly on all of those however in IE the modal opens and that's it.  It simply refuses to run anything after the modal is open.

I've tried to bind the event with .on('click',...), .bind('click',...) and .click(...) and all those methods work on every other browser.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on further research it turns out that you can't bind events to option elements within a select on IE version 8 onwards.

To get around this we need to bind to the 'change' event on the select